# echo variable name in for loop

Tags: bash, function, for-loop

I am trying to create a helper function for developing my scripts that prints the name and value of each parameter passed to the function.

Doing this with a single variable can be achieved by shell parameter expansion like:

```
foo=bar
var_name=${!foo@}
echo $var_name    # foo
echo $foo         # bar
```

Doing the same in a function like this:

```
write_params() {
  for var in "$@"; do
    echo "${!var@} === $var"
  done
}
```

Calling it with the following call

```
write_params $SOURCE $TARGET $pwd
```

Would in my world give me the following output

```
SOURCE === <source value>
TARGET === <target value>
pwd === <pwd value>
```

but it gives me the following output now:

```
var === <source value>
var === <target value>
var === <pwd value>
```

Sure there is some magic I can use here, but I haven't found it after some searching now so I'll ask here.

**Edit:**
As reported in the comments the following solution works:

```
write_params() {
  for var in "$@"; do
    echo "$var === ${!var}"
  done
}
```

if you pass the variables in the function like this:

```
write_params SOURCE TARGET pwd
```

Comment: `echo ${!var@}" === $var"` ?

Comment: Is `write_params` is being called within a bash script or from console?

Comment: Er, won't `write_params $SOURCE $TARGET $pwd` result in `write_params value1 value2 value3`? Shouldn't the call be `write_params SOURCE TARGET pwd`?

Comment: @Avihoo Yes it is called within the same bash script

Comment: @Biffen no, I want the stored values as well, sending it SOURCE TARGET will just type the names out, I wan't that as well as the parameter value

Comment: If you pass in the values you **cannot** get the variable names back. If you pass in the names then you can use the indirect expansion `${!var}` to get the value of the variable with that name. That's the point. `var=value; echo "${var}"; indirect=var; echo "$indirect - ${!indirect}"`

Comment: @Andreas From where is the function supposed to get the variables' *names*?

Comment: @Biffen from the items sent in to the function. so in my example it would be SOURCE, TARGET and pwd variables and their respective value. Problem is that I put them into var now and that prints var all the time. I wan't the names passed to the function.

Comment: @Etan looks like it worked with using the names as you suggested, thank you.

echo "$var => ${!var}" in the loop and passing as names instead of variables.